# Laravel 5.5, List of checkboxes (products), If user has product(s), checkboxes must be checked for those products

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a user table with a column named products, while adding users theres a list of checkboxes (products), I am able to add the products while ticking the checkboxes.

The problem is in edit user, if user has a product (abc), that abc checkbox should be checked (ticked) in edit user screen. I am not able to do that. Please Help. 
Thanks in advance. Below is the code

**Thats How I am calling the products with checkboxes**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{ Form::open([ 'files' => true, 'method' => 'post', 'route' => 'users.edit', 'class' => 'form']) }}
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 0; line-height: 50px; height: 50px;">
   <h4 class="module-title">Create User</h4>
</div>
<br clear="both"/>
@if (session('alert'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
   {{ session('alert') }}
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
   <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
         <th>
            Username
         </th>
         <td>
            {{ Form::text('username',$user->username, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            New Password
         </th>
         <td>
            {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            Role
         </th>
         <td>
            <div class="form-group">
               <select name="select_list1" class="form-control">
                  @if ($user->role == "admin")
                  <option value="admin" selected="selected">Admin</option>
                  <option value="user">User</option>
                  @endif
                  @if ($user->role == "user")
                  <option value="user" selected="selected">User</option>
                  <option value="user">Admin</option>
                  @endif
               </select>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="products">
         <th>
            Product Type<br/>(After Changes please re-login)
         </th>
         <td>
            <table>
               @foreach($products as $product)
               <tr>
                  <td style="width: 32%;  padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{$product->name}}">
                     {{$product->name2}}
                  </td>
               </tr>
               @endforeach
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>
            Active
         </th>
         <td>
            <div class="form-group">
               <select name="select_list2" class="form-control">
                  @if ($user->active == 1)
                  <option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
                  <option value="0">No</option>
                  @endif
                  @if ($user->active == 0)
                  <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
                  <option value="1">Yes</option>
                  @endif
               </select>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <hr/>
   <button type="Submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">
   Save
   </button>
   <br clear="both"/>
   <br/>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: If the user has multiple products checked then how you store that?

Comment: @DsRaj

$products = implode(" , ", $request->get('products'));

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => 'example',
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'role' => $request->select_list1,
            'products' => $products,
            'active' => $request->select_list2,

        ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'User Added.');

Comment: I mean how you store that in database 
Let's say you store name as string Hashaam 
then single product name as 'abc' but what about multiple?

Comment: abc , abcd   (thats how i m saving it in db)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if user `existing` product `match` a product from `product list` and make it `checked`.

```
<?php $products_array = explode(",",$user->products);?>
@foreach($products as $product)
           <tr>
              <td style="width: 32%;  padding-bottom: 5px;">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{$product->name}}" @if(in_array($product->name2, $products_array)) checked @endif>
                 {{$product->name2}}
              </td>
           </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Great!!, that works if user has one product.
but what if user has more than one product as I am saving more than one products using implode for example (Scanner , Ink)

Comment: you could use `strpos` in `if` block to check if a product name exists in that column of that user

Comment: @HashaamAhmed I have edited my answer, it will work with your scenarios

Comment: @HashaamAhmed its ok now, make a try again with updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Laravel Collective` , `select` field to achieve that, take a look at the code below:

```
Form::select('select_list1', ['user' => 'User', 'admin' => 'Admin'], $user->role, ['placeholder' => 'Choose a role']);
```

**First parameter** represents the name of this field.

**Second parameter** represents the array of data you wish to present in order `key => value`.

**Third parameter** represents the `default` value, if theres no default value, you can use `null`

**Fourth parameter (Optional)** represents the array of attributes to use on the form element (class, placeholder, id, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check if your product match with your user product
if you save `product code` in your user's table, then your code should be like this

```
<table>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
           <td style="width: 32%;  padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{$product->name}}" {{$user->productCode == $product->code ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                 {{$product->name2}}
           </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

but if you save `product name` in your user's table, then your code should be like this

```
<table>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
           <td style="width: 32%;  padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{$product->name}}" {{$user->productName == $product->name ? 'checked' : ''}}>
                 {{$product->name2}}
           </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

The point is, you only need to match between your product table and user table item. This is like filtering all the items with the same value. After you get all of the value, then check it.

Hope this can help you ;)

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)), but i tried that it only works if user has only one product. for multiple products I have marked one of the ans above which works perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you store product in product column like this: 'abc','abc1','abc2'

```
<?php $userProductArr = explode(',',$user->products); ?>
@foreach($products as $product)
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 32%;  padding-bottom: 5px;">
         <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="{{$product->name}}" {{(in_array($product->name,$userProductArr) ?  checked : '' }}>
         {{$product->name2}}
      </td>
   </tr>
```

@endforeach